# Apply PHP version with .htaccess on specific file only

Tags: php, .htaccess, php-7

I set new PHP7 version with .htaccess at root, but few files in subdirectories show errors and I want to set with .htaccess PHP v5.6 only for this files. Is this possible?

```
Action application/x-httpd-php70 /cgi-sys/php70-fcgi-starter.fcgi
AddType application/x-httpd-php70 .php .php70
```

Comment: Put an `AddType` in the `Directory` module.